# Analysis: True or False

Tags: analysis, algorithms

I have to answer these as true or false with logic why it is? But I have no idea how to state these as true or false?

a. True or False?
i. $\log_3 n = O(\log_2 n)$?
ii. $3^n = \Omega(2^n)$?
iii. $\sqrt{n} = O(\log_2 n)$?
iv. $\log_2 n = \Omega (\sqrt{n})$?
v. $3n^2 +\sqrt{n} = Θ(n^2)$?

Note: 2 and 3 after log is base number.

Comment: You know the definitions. Have you seen examples? State what examples you've seen. (If you don't know the definitions of $O,\Omega,\Theta$, then look them up)

Comment: It is not a home work service. Show what have you tried.

Comment: You should give more context to your question. Which parts are you struggling with? What have you tried? Do you understand the terms that appear in your question? Any information will be useful for people to create better answers for you.

Comment: for first I figured this out: Big O doesn't deal with constant factors, and the difference between Logx(n) and Logy(n) is a constant factor. It is because changing the base of logarithms is equal to multiplying it by a constant. And big O does not care about constants.

Answer (score 2):

1. $\log3 n \leq C \log 2n\implies 3n \leq (2n)^C.$ If we choose $C=2$ then clearly for $n\geq 3$, $3n\leq 4n^2$  so this is true.
2. $2^n \leq 3^n$ for $n\geq 1$ so $3^n =\Omega(2^n).$
3. $\sqrt{n} \leq C \log 2n\implies \limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\log 2n}$ is finite. But this is not true as $\limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\log 2n} = +\infty.$

This should give you some idea to do the rest.

Comment: thanks......your answer helped me a lot. Know I know how to solve this.

Comment: No problem, next time give more details to your questions and also include your attempt to solve the problem.